# Monkey patching class and instance in Python

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I am confused with following difference. Say I have this class with some use case:

```py
class C:
    def f(self, a, b, c=None):
        print(f"Real f called with {a=}, {b=} and {c=}.")


my_c = C()
my_c.f(1, 2, c=3)  # Output: Real f called with a=1, b=2 and c=3.
```

I can monkey patch it for purpose of testing like this:

```py
class C:
    def f(self, a, b, c=None):
        print(f"Real f called with {a=}, {b=} and {c=}.")


def f_monkey_patched(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print(f"Patched f called with {args=} and {kwargs=}.")


C.f = f_monkey_patched
my_c = C()
my_c.f(1, 2, c=3)  # Output: Patched f called with args=(1, 2) and kwargs={'c': 3}.
```

So far so good. But I would like to patch only one single instance and it somehow consumes first argument:

```py
class C:
    def f(self, a, b, c=None):
        print(f"Real f called with {a=}, {b=} and {c=}.")


def f_monkey_patched(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print(f"Patched f called with {args=} and {kwargs=}.")


my_c = C()
my_c.f = f_monkey_patched
my_c.f(1, 2, c=3)  # Output: Patched f called with args=(2,) and kwargs={'c': 3}.
```

Why has been first argument consumed as `self` instead of the instance itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions in Python are descriptors; when they're attached to a class, but looked up on an instance of the class, the descriptor protocol gets invoked, producing a bound method on your behalf (so `my_c.f`, where `f` is defined on the *class*, is distinct from the actual function `f` you originally defined, and implicitly passes `my_c` as `self`).

If you want to make a replacement that shadows the class `f` only for a specific instance, but still passes along the instance as `self` like you expect, you need to *manually* bind the instance to the function to create the bound method using the (admittedly terribly documented) [`types.MethodType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MethodType):

```
from types import MethodType  # The class implementing bound methods in Python 3

# ... Definition of C and f_monkey_patched unchanged

my_c = C()
my_c.f = MethodType(f_monkey_patched, my_c)  # Creates a pre-bound method from the function and
                                             # the instance to bind to
```

Being bound, `my_c.f` will now behave as a function that does not accept `self` from the caller, but when called `self` will be received as the instance bound to `my_c` at the time the `MethodType` was constructed.

---

**Update with performance comparisons**:

Looks like, performance-wise, all the solutions are similar enough as to be irrelevant performance-wise ([Kedar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73545480/364696) explicit use of the descriptor protocol and my use of `MethodType` are equivalent, and the fastest, but the percentage difference over `functools.partial` is so small that it won't matter under the weight of any useful work you're doing):

```
>>> # ... define C as per OP
>>> def f_monkey_patched(self, a):  # Reduce argument count to reduce unrelated overhead
...     pass

>>> from types import MethodType
>>> from functools import partial
>>> partial_c, mtype_c, desc_c = C(), C(), C()
>>> partial_c.f = partial(f_monkey_patched, partial_c)
>>> mtype_c.f = MethodType(f_monkey_patched, mtype_c)
>>> desc_c.f = f_monkey_patched.__get__(desc_c, C)
>>> %%timeit x = partial_c  # Swapping in partial_c, mtype_c or desc_c
... x.f(1)
...
```

I'm not even going to give exact timing outputs for the IPython `%%timeit` magic, as it varied across runs, even on a desktop without CPU throttling involved. All I could say for sure is that `partial` was reliably a little slower, but only by a matter of ~1 ns (the other two typically ran in 56-56.5 ns, the `partial` solution typically took 56.5-57.5), and it took quite a lot of paring of extraneous stuff (e.g. switching from `%timeit` reading the names from global scope causing `dict` lookups to caching to a local name in `%%timeit` to use simple array lookups) to even get the differences that predictable.

Point is, any of them work, performance-wise. I'd personally recommend either my `MethodType` or Kedar's explicit use of descriptor protocol approach (they are identical in end result AFAICT; both produce the same bound method class), whichever one looks prettier to you, as it means the bound method *is* actually a bound method (so you can extract `.__self__` and `.__func__` like you would on any bound method constructed the normal way, where `partial` requires you to switch to `.args[0]` and `.func` to get the same info).

Comment: For the nitpicky: On modern CPython, "the descriptor protocol gets invoked, producing a bound method on your behalf" is a bit of a lie; it avoids creating bound methods in many cases, because it can recognize the common scenario and the interpreter itself fudges things, passing along the `self` directly to the underlying function without actually creating a bound method object when you perform both lookup and call in a single expression without storing the bound method. But when that optimization doesn't apply, a true bound method is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the function to bound method by calling its `__get__` method (since all function as [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) as well, thus have this method)

```
def t(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)

class Test():
    pass
Test.t = t.__get__(Test(), Test) # binding to the instance of Test
```

For example

```
Test().t(1,2, x=1, y=2)
(<__main__.Test object at 0x7fd7f6d845f8>, 1, 2)
{'y': 2, 'x': 1}
```

Note that the instance is also passed as an positional argument. That is if you want you function to be instance method, the function should have been written in such a way that first argument behaves as instance of the class. Else, you can bind the function to None instance and the class, which will be like `staticmethod`.

```
Test.tt = t.__get__(None, Test)
Test.tt(1,2,x=1, y=2)
(1, 2)
{'y': 2, 'x': 1}
```

Furthermore, to make it a `classmethod` (first argument is class):

```
Test.ttt = t.__get__(Test, None) # bind to class
Test.ttt(1,2, x=1, y=2)
(<class '__main__.Test'>, 1, 2)
{'y': 2, 'x': 1}
```

Comment: Nice alternative to using `types.MethodType` explicitly. I'm a little leery of manually calling special methods (it feels... unclean; when at all possible I prefer to invoke them implicitly, partially because there are subtle distinctions in how they're looked up when called implicitly [usually looked up directly on the class efficiently without checking the instance] vs. explicitly [looked up on the instance first, which is slower and risks incorrect behavior where it might read an instance version incorrectly]), but it's a reasonable use here.

Comment: I think you should be demonstrating these uses on an instance of `Test` though, not `Test` itself (the OP's goal is to monkey-patch an instance with a new bound method; this is attaching bound methods to classes).

Answer (score 1):

When you do `C.f = f_monkey_patched`, and later instantiate an object of `C`, the function is *bound* to that object, effectively doing something like

```
obj.f = functools.partial(C.f, obj)
```

When you call `obj.f(...)`, you are actually calling the partially bound function, i.e. `f_monkey_patched(obj, ...)`

On the other hand, doing `my_c.f = f_monkey_patched`, you assign the function as-is to the attribute `my_c.f`. When you call `my_c.f(...)`, those arguments are passed to the function as-is, so `self` is the first argument you passed, i.e. `1`, and the remaining arguments go to `*args`

Comment: Yep, I saw you edited it just before I hit submit on my comment. :-) I will say, while this works (and I don't hate it or anything), I do think, as a matter of behaving as similarly as possible to the non-patched code, it's better to make a true bound method (whether by my method or Kedar's doesn't really matter) than to simulate one slightly imprecisely with `functools.partial`. `functools.partial` can't be manipulated the same way (it has no concept of `.__self__` or `.__func__`, so you have to treat it differently), and unlike bound methods, it has no core interpreter optimizations.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I agree, I figured `partial` might make for a better analogy since I learned about `partial` before I learned about `MethodType`, and that was good enough to explain why OP sees the behavior they see. I planned on adding a "what _actually_ happens is `MethodType`" section, but you added an answer before I could get to it :)